# php script to run the terminal commad and to give the result over terminal

Tags: php, linux

This is the script that creates a file using php script, but unable to give the result of the later command. how can i run the script so that i can get result over the terminal itself.
this is snapshot of the code that uses touch to create a file and ls -lh to find all the list of files in that folder:

[image: this is snapshot of the code that uses touch to create a file and ls -lh to find all the list of files in that folder]

now i can see that a new file is created using touch but ls -lh command failed to give result:

[image: now i can see that a new file is created using touch but ls -lh command failed to give result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `shell_exec`:

```
$r = shell_exec($cmd);
var_dump($r);
```

You'll see result received from shell.

In your case:

```
<?php

$cmd1 = 'touch /tmp/x.tmp';
$r1 = shell_exec($cmd1);
var_dump($r1);

$cmd2 = 'ls -lh /tmp/x.tmp';
$r2 = shell_exec($cmd2);
var_dump($r2);
```

Will return:

```
/tmp/x.php:5:
NULL
/tmp/x.php:9:
string(54) "-rw-r--r--  1 k  wheel     0B Jan 11 13:36 /tmp/x.tmp
```